# Hover with multiple ID/Class

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML which works:

```
<div class="preview">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="SomeFile/SomeImage.gif">
        </div>
        <h2>Some heading</h2>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
```

And the following CSS (which works):

```
.preview:hover > h2 {display: none;}
.preview:hover > p {display: block;}
```

If I add a new  `<div id="newID">` around the HTML, how do I update the CSS to work with the new ID wrapper?

Also, how do I use multiple IDs in the CSS to avoid re-writing this for each ID?

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with using a class as you are now?

Comment: Your question isn't exactly clear. And your second question is exactly what classes are for. Classes allow you to apply the same CSS to multiple elements on the page at the same time. ID's are unique identifiers and really only necessary when you actually have to identify a specific element on the page.

Comment: The code you have now works fine, I still don't get the point of adding a div with an id as a wrapper. https://jsfiddle.net/p2p32bqz/

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - the reason being is that I am using Javascript to edit each one seperately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the style to be applied only to the elements that are children to the new wrapper, then you can just add the ID selector like this:

```
#newID .preview:hover > h2 {display: none;}
```

Otherwise you don't need to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you looking for?

```
<div id="newID">
    <div class="preview">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="SomeFile/SomeImage.gif">
            </div>
            <h2>Some heading</h2>
            <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="preview">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="SomeFile/SomeImage.gif">
            </div>
            <h2>Some heading</h2>
            <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

your css:

```
#newID .preview:hover > h2 {display: none;}
#newID .preview:hover > p {display: block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class for styling multiple elements with the same style:

```
.yourClass:hover {}
```

Comment: I know this is possible but it must be an ID in this case

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand what you're looking for, but if you are trying to apply the css to newly added `divs` then you can try this

```
<html><head>
<style>
.preview { border: 1px solid black;width:200px}
.preview:hover > h2 {display: none;}
.preview:hover > p {display: block;}
</style>
<script src=path/to/jquery.js></script>
</head><body>

<button class=plus>Add</button>
<div class="preview">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="SomeFile/SomeImage.gif">
        </div>
        <h2>Some heading</h2>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>


<script>

// Button Adds a new div with the class 'preview'
$('button.plus').click(function () {
  var new_id = '<div id="newID" class=preview>New Div <br/> <h2>Some heading</h2> <p>Some text</p></div>';
  $('body').append(new_id);
});



</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If your ID use same structure, for example #newid-x, #newid-y, #newid-z, you can write you css rule targeting all ID start with newid-

```
div[id^='newid-']:hover > h2, div[id*=' newid-']:hover >h2 {
    display: none;
}
```